# Override template file

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, extensions

I want to list category page in magento which is located in 
\app\design\frontend\default\\template\catalog\product\list.phtml.

In app\design\frontend\default\modern\layout\catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

But the list.phtml is overrided by a extension having

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/extensionname/product/list.phtml‌

and its xml with

```
<reference name="product_list">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/product/list.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

How to display category page from my theme's list.phtml.

Comment: `<catalog_category_default>` add your code inside this tag

Comment: I have tried putting the code inside <catalog_category_default> but it does not override extension's list.phtml file. @MeenakshiSundaramR

Comment: have you try `<catalog_category_layered>`

Comment: Yes but it too doesn't work. @MeenakshiSundaramR

Comment: there is bug in your layout remove one double quote from `method="setTemplate""` to `method="setTemplate"`

Comment: I have tested it as **method="setTemplate"** only.Is there a way to override **app/design/frontend/default/default/template/<extensionname>/product/list.phtml** in my custom template.@MeenakshiSundaramR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14731/discussion-between-meenakshi-sundaram-r-and-abinaya).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create local.xml in layout folder and set

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/your/list.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: local.xml load last and if you override some config in this file it's apply instead other config

Answer (score 0):

You said, For some reasons your `list.phtml` file is overrided by a extensions. So you can use the overrided `list.phtml` for listing a category page. you cant set 2 default file(list.phtml) for a template.